# How to define row space in dynamic

Tags: html, css

There is a doubt when i finish my HTML page 
   How to define row space in web page?

```
<br /> and <p></p> Isn't the answer what i want.
```

Because it's static,and what i want is dynamic.
   I can define the row space by px or em.
   Is there a property like width: 5px or height: 5px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
<p style="line-height: 20px">Row of text</p>
```

Comment: yeah,it's effective,line-height,thanks. can i define only the top row space or bottom space? line-height is define both top and bottom

Comment: You can use `margin-top`, `margin-bottom`, `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` - experiment with them and you'll see